# Block rendering gets skipped in included template chunk

Tags: django

I'm willing to include a shared code block to templates that extend a different template.
Here's a page that gets rendered and 2 variants of the base template.

*page.html*:

```
{% extends "base_form.html"%}
{% block legend %}legend{% endblock %}
```

**Variant 1**:

*base_form.html*:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

    {% block body %}
        {% block legend %}{% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
```

rendered:

```
legend
```

**Variant 2**:

*base_form.html*:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

    {% block body %}
        {% include "chunks/form.html" %}
    {% endblock %}
```

*chunks/form.html*:

```
coming from a chunk
{% block legend %}{% endblock %}
```

rendered:

```
coming from a chunk
```

So the block gets skipped in the second case. Oddly enough, everything works with django-debug-toolbar enabled.
A bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue - there's [a ticket for it](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6646) which is marked as accepted in Django's bug tracker.